# Vaadin 10 Dialog doesn't show up

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin10

I can't see my `Vaadin Dialog` which I'm trying to add on a simple `Vertical Layout`
Here is my code:

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(new Label("Simple label"));
d.setCloseOnEsc(false);
d.setCloseOnOutsideClick(false);

Button cancelBtn = new Button("Cancel", event ->  {
    d.close();
});

d.add(cancelBtn);
add(d);
```

I hope anyone can help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `Dialog::open`

A [`Dialog`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.5/com/vaadin/flow/component/dialog/Dialog.html) is a specific component - it is not normally rendered within the given container, but opens as a popup. Therefore, it has special semantics to make it to render - after creating a dialog, you have to call [`dialog.open()`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.5/com/vaadin/flow/component/dialog/Dialog.html#open--) to make it display.

This is also not specific to Vaadin - in many frameworks, dialogs (and other popups) are displayed in a special manner - it's somewhat of a pattern.